# gdb error handling within a user-defined command

Tags: gdb, user-defined-functions

It's really annoying that gdb automatically continues execution on the 'jump' command, so I've set up a short 'j' command in gdb to combine tbreak and jump to set a temporary breakpoint and jump to it with a single command.  This works great - except...  If the location I specify is not in the current stack frame, the jump command attempts to warn me, but this happens:

```
Line 2810 is not in `TDAClearFields'.  Jump anyway? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

and it jumps there anyway.  Is there a way in a user-defined command to provide a default answer of 'n' for this error condition so that a typo in my 'j' command doesn't result in crashing the program?